# Why is this JSON coming out as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why would this JSON be undefined when I call `json.bridge_time`?

```
{"tunnel_time": 0,"bridge_time": 0}
```

If it makes a difference, here is the code where I am calling it:

```
$.get( "http://localhost:8000/us", function(json){
console.log(json);
    $('#timeone').html(json.bridge_time + "min delay");
    $('#timetwo').html(json.tunnel_time + "min delay");
})
.fail(function(){
    alert('We can\'t get data right now! Please try again later.');
})
.done(function(){
    alert('Success!');
});
```

Comment: try adding `'json'` as third argument of `$.get` to set dataType, or try `$.getJSON`

Comment: @Shomz what do you mean?

Comment: That's the `console.log` output of `json`? Is it an object or a string? What `Content-Type` header is the end point sending?

Comment: what does `console.log(json)` show?

Comment: @kennypu it comes out like I said in my question

Comment: @charlietfl like so: `$.get( "http://localhost:8000/us", dataType: "json" function(json){`?

Comment: When I enter this in the chrome console: `JSON.parse('{"tunnel_time": 0,"bridge_time": 0}').bridge_time` it returns `0` like expected

Comment: `alert(typeof json)` if it comes as string. Either you need to parse it or ask server to return json

Comment: no...`$.get('url',func(){},'json')`..`$.getJSON` will do same thing for you. Sending wrong header from server is all

Comment: @charlietfl would you PLEASE put your comments into an answer so I can upvote/accept it? That last one just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that due to header being sent , jQuery ajax isn't recognizing data as `json`. You can set `dataType` of `$.get` so jQuery knows to expect `json`, or use `$.getJSON` which will already has `dataType` set

Using `$.get`

```
$.get('url',function(response){
   /*response  should be object now*/
},'json');/* last argument is "dataType" */
```

**[See $.get() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)**

Should also look into setting proper `Content-Type` header at server for `application/json`